# Refresh one JFrame from another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

The 2 frame are running.
If I update the 2 frame so I want to be updated to 1 (first one) automatically.

I've already tried:

```
frame.invalidate();
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```

---

```
frame.repaint();
repaint();
revalidate();
```

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 4) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: Thanx Sir....Next time i kept in mind.....

Comment: The first two comments need to be 'kept in mind' sooner, rather than later.